# how to animate scroll all the way down to the bottom of the window

Tags: jquery

I have a list of comments. When a user submits a new comment it is appended to the end of the list. This causes the user to need to scrolldown to see the appended comment.

I want to auto scroll down in an animated way.

How can I animate scroll down to the bottom of the window?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scrollTop to scroll the page.  If you know the element that was appended you can scroll to it's offset top like this:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top + "px"});
```

EDIT:
To scroll to the very bottom:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() + "px"});
```